# tsconfig paths not working with vue/node project

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to set up tsconfig file for a vue app to take advantage of the paths property. The project started off initially as a vue-cli project, but now I need to restructure the project to add node/express/mongo. I've read the ts docs on the ["paths" property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping%20docs). I'm still getting the following errors:
At first it lists all my vue component typescript files, vuex store typescript files, and my types.ts which is where I have definitions for custom types and says it cannot find them.

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 23 errors                               4:14:16 AM

These dependencies were not found:

* @/components/../...vue

...

ERROR in C:/Development/my-project/client/src/views/my-view/MyView.ts(5,38):
5:38 Cannot find module '@/types/types' or its corresponding type declarations.
    3 | 
    4 | import { Action, Getter, State } from 'vuex-class';
  > 5 | import { User, UserState } from '@/types/types';
```

the structure of the project is as follows:

```
/my-project
  /client
    /public
    /src
      /components
      ...
      App.vue
      main.ts
  /server
    server.js
    config.js
    db.js
tsconfig.json
tsconfig.app.json
vue.config.js
.eslintrc.js
...
```

My tsconfig is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My tsconfig.app is as follows:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./client",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "client/src/**/*.ts",
    "client/src/**/*.tsx",
    "client/src/**/*.vue",
    "client/tests/**/*.ts",
    "client/tests/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

and for reference my vue.config is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');

function addStyleResource(rule) {
    rule.use('style-resource')
        .loader('style-resources-loader')
        .options({
            patterns: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, './client/src/styles/style.scss')
            ]
        });
}

module.exports = {
    assetsDir: 'client/src/assets',
    indexPath: 'client/public/index.html',

    pages: {
        index: {
            entry: 'client/src/main.ts'
        }
    },

    chainWebpack: config => {
        const types = ['vue-modules', 'vue', 'normal-modules', 'normal'];
        types.forEach(type => addStyleResource(config.module.rule('scss').oneOf(type)));
    },

    publicPath: '/client',

};
```